# Change a DataTable to array of array

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that has a lot of fields.

I want to care about these fields, which are `Campaign`, `Hour` and `Minutes`

I want to take the data for each `Campaign`, then add the `Hour` and `Minutes` values in array like this:

```
[[Hour, Minute], [Hour, Minute], [Hour, Minute]....[Hour, Minute]]
```

#### I tried

`DTgraph` is the datatable variable.
To get all the `Campaign`:

```
var compainNames = (from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
                          group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
                          select new
                          {
                              CampaignName = grp.Key
                          }).ToList();
```

Then, to take the data for each `Campaign`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < compainNames.Count(); i++) {
    Int64[][] array = new Int64[][] { };
    var dataForOneCampaint = DTgraph.Select("Campaign = " + compainNames[i].ToString()).ToList();
    for (int j = 0; j < dataForOneCampaint.Count(); j++) { 
        array[1] = ...
    }
}
```

I know that I can take the values like this:

```
dataForOneCampaint[index].Field<Decimal>("Hour"))
```

**But I didn't know how to fill the `array`. 
Could you help me please?**

Comment: why you need to group by Campaign? Is there any chance that one campaign has multiple rows and in that case how to calculate Campaign's Hour & Minute?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var compainNames = (from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
                      group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
                      select new
                      {
                          CampaignName = grp.Key
                      }).ToList().ToArray();
```